# The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator

Tags: 2010, list, list-view

I came up with this error on one of my My SharePoint 2010 sites. I know the reason for this error but the interesting thing is, my list has only 3500 items, and the List View Threshold is 5000 as default. So why i am encountering this error? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you recently add any Lookup Columns? Remember that People fields are also considered lookup columns.  I think the threshold on those, in SP2010 is 8(?).

Answer (score 1):

Items in the recycle bin also count towards the limit; make sure you did not delete items from this list recently and if you did, remove them from the recycle bin too.

You can also check that the default LVT of 5000 items has not been lowered in the Central Administration page.

Comment: thank you for your concern. but there are no items in recycle bin, and i checked the CA and LVT is 5000.

Comment: So, what is the offending operation?

Answer (score -2):

Indexing the list might help you fix this issue.

Comment: Please extend this answer with more details about how to index a list, and what that means in terms of e.g. performance, to make your answer more helpful :)